# How to make Kinetic js work on IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, kineticjs

I know this question has been posted many times, but I didn't find any solution in all the posts I read. I'm using Kinetic JS to display images. It works fine on Chrome and FF but images don't show up on IE.
I tried to add this line to my index file :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1, IE=edge">
```

as it is suggested here [KineticJS wont load in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900608/kineticjs-wont-load-in-internet-explorer)
But it is still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KineticJS does not and will not have < IE9 support. As stated by Eric Rowell the developer of KineticJS.

The reason for this is because KineticJS uses `<canvas>` but IE8 and below does not support the `<canvas>` tag, so nothing will render.

You will be better off using [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) as it supports VML for IE and SVG for the other browsers.