# struts1.2 IE11 Compatability issues

Tags: browser, migration, struts, internet-explorer-11, struts-1

Struts 1.2 application is not working in IE 11 without the compatibility view unchecked.

With the compatibility view enabled, the application seems to be working fine. The goal is to make the application work without the compatibility settings.

I tried the below options of using meta tags in `<head>` of our application, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

**Option 1:**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

I tried deploying code using  the above tag in head tag in  core JSP pages(when the application get started,first theses pages will load),which our application should load after refresh  but didn’t in native mode.

(main.jsp,home.jsp,blank.jsp,tableData.jsp)

**Option 2:**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

**Option3 :**

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` .Tried using this tag and few jars but still the same.

Any sort of suggestions would be much appreciated, otherwise I would need to migrate 120 thousand source lines of codes to Struts 2.X.

Comment: You will have to give out a lot more information before this can be answered in any meaningful way.

Comment: Actually, if the app is written well, you'd only need to convert the actions and JSP. That aside, what specifically is going wrong? I mean, the framework itself doesn't care about the browser. The old S1 tags should be emitting standard HTML that, while crusty and decrepit, is still just standard HTML. So, what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility mode (aka: quirksmode) may be triggered for another reason: That mode is triggered when you're loading the page from an intranet.

Check if that mode is activated when the page is loaded on IE

You may check the answer given in another post:

[Internet Explorer 11 disable “display intranet sites in compatibility view” via meta tag not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557299/internet-explorer-11-disable-display-intranet-sites-in-compatibility-view-via)