# Application opening in IE7 mode by default on IE11

Tags: java, internet-explorer-11

When I am opening my application deployed on server, the IE mode is getting set to default IE7 (I checked in developer tools). I need when I open, it should open as IE edge mode. This issue is not browser specific but code specific as all other apps are working fine as IE11 mode.

I am also setting the compatibility mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"></meta>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
```

Do I need to make any other changes?

Comment: Can you copy paste all your code in different application and than try to run ? if it is possible

Comment: Not possible Harshil

Answer (score 1):

When you open localhost or "intranet" sites in IE11 it will automatically assume you want to render it in IE7 mode (God knows why). There is a setting to turn this off in IE. Referenced here [Internet Explorer 11 disable "display intranet sites in compatibility view" via meta tag not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557299/internet-explorer-11-disable-display-intranet-sites-in-compatibility-view-via)