# display: flex won't render properly in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have this code:

```css
.fbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="fbox">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

And instead of getting this:

[image: expected result]

I get this:

[image: actual result]

As far as it's stated on caniuse and other relevant sources, the `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` should be supported by Internet Explorer 11.

The version I tested with is: IE 11.1.18343.0

Does anybody have idea why?

Comment: It looks fine in my IE browser. Are you sure you are using IE11? You can swap the version for testing

Comment: @MarcHjorth that's what the `About IE` says... so I guess it's lying.

Comment: working for me in IE 11.967.16299.0

Comment: When I emulate say IE 10, it still says IE11 in the about

Comment: It's true  that I'm testing in windows 10, maybe they did something to it? I'm downloading another one from microsoft... let's see

Comment: add `-ms-flex-direction: row;` and check again, I guess box should have `flex with a value`

Comment: @RachidRhafour tried but without success.

Comment: Have you checked your compatibility mode? (press f12 and select compatibility mode or emulation on tabs) - this works fine in my ie11 on windows 10

Comment: @Pete Ok so that was it, basically Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 10, defaults in compatibility mode for IE 7... Write your answer and I will vote for it.

Comment: Note that IE may default to compatibility mode for localhost URLs, but certainly not for everything. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37460492/1016716) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25557299/1016716). Unless someone changed that on your computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout works fine on IE11.

However, you may need to check the browser's compatibility setting.

Press F12, go to the "Emulation" tab, and check that "Document Mode" is set to IE11.