# Connect to a site via SSL/DavWWWRoot not usual URL? Why does this make a difference?

Tags: html, ssl, url, sharepoint, internet-explorer-8

Follow on from this question:

[Can i over-ride IE enterprise mode from HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537046/can-i-over-ride-ie-enterprise-mode-from-html)

I succeeded, in hosting a D3 SVG visualisation on my company sharepoint site.

**The Initial Issue:**
My internal company sharepoint site has enterprise mode settings in IE that was forcing me from IE11 into an IE8 environment per my console:

```
HTML1122: Internet Explorer is running in Enterprise Mode emulating IE8.
```

**The workaround:** 
Connect to site via the SSL in the browser, not via http/https URL. The connection looks something like this: file://xxx.xxx.xx.xx.net@ssl/DavWWWRoot/xxx/xxx/index.html

I type it in the browser where a URL would go and it loads up perfectly. Albeit a little slowly.

**The question:** the work around was a suggestion that wasn't fully explained to me but works a treat.
What exactly is happening here? Could someone explain what the file I am accessing is and why the sharepoint rules don't apply? Does this process by pass any security I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you're accessing your web server using the [WebDAV Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-webdav/using-the-webdav-redirector#introduction) which is a feature specific to Windows.

A WebDAV endpoint is a web server that supports [WebDav, a standard protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2518)  over HTTP or HTTPS transport.
Basically, WebDAV allows to expose a pseudo file system (files and folders) over HTTP(S). SharePoint does support WebDAV.

So, the Windows WebDAV redirector is an OS driver that "mounts" the WebDav pseudo remote file system as a virtual file system, so it can be seen like by all Windows apps like a "drive" (it's similar to what happens when you "mount" an ISO disk).

The document explains how you can manually connect to a WebDAV endpoint. In this case, you will get a drive letter.
But you can connect implicitely, which is what happens here, this is why the '`DavWWWRoot`' keyword exists (it's known to Windows), to allow for implicit connections, w/o having to map the drive explicitely.

So this file path:

```
\\myserver\DavWWWRoot\mypath\myfile.ext
```

will implicitely connect to the myserver WebDav HTTP server, though the WebDAV redirector. It is equivalent to this url with a `file` scheme:

```
 file://myserver/DavWWWRoot/mypath/myfile.ext
```

`@ssl` is another hardcoded keyword trick that instructs the WebDav redirector to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

So, in the end, it means you're accessing the SharePoint file using HTTPS, but as a file on a remote disk (like a share). There is no security breach per se (WebDav redirector uses HTTPS authentication, etc.) but IE rules may be different, it depends on your IE settings.