# What can cause a local ASP.NET MVC site to display incompletely only due to using a different UNC path?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, dns, windows-server-2016, asp.net-mvc-5.2, iis-10

**Context:** Local network with a `VS2017` boilerplate `MVC5` application loaded onto a `separate 2016 Server running IIS Web Server`.  The following series of screenshots shows the problem.

**Using the direct IP address of the server running IIS** the site displays and operates properly as shown.  You can see the standard MVC menu structure.

[image]

But **using the Host Name** in the local network's DNS, the site displays incorrectly.  And to be clear, the 'hamburger symbol' is not present in the first image displayed above.  You can also see the menu structure is missing and the page display is corrupted, but clearly the site is being reached.

[image]

Why does the site display incorrectly simply because I used a different UNC path to reach the application?  I realize I may have other problems that I'm simply not experienced enough to know are significant issues.

I have used hosting providers extensively but I have never really used the IIS web server to host a local site.  This is the binding for the site:

[image]

It seems like the css is not executing correctly, but I don't understand why that happens using a different UNC path.

**Debug screens added** per request in comments (easier to read at 200%).  There were errors in Console as well as Network.  I will also add that the site displays OK in Chrome and Firefox, but I want to understand the issue and make it work in IE.  These errors occur in IE 11.

[image]

[image]

This error log is from Firefox

[image]

Comment: Bring up the developer tools in the browser, go to the Network tab, refresh the page and see which requests are failing and why.

Comment: I will add the readouts in the main post

Comment: Also, when I run the app in Chrome, no errors are found.  But in Firefox, there is a curious error which leads me to believe I've installed the site in IIS incorrectly.  I'm posting the Firefox Console errors also.

Comment: The console errors in IE11 are explained on the second line. The page is using compatibility mode because it is on the intranet and "Display intranet sites in compatibility view" is checked. [Uncheck it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25557299/11683), or add [required tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26463309/11683) to your page.

Comment: I added as the first meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` as in your referenced post and it seems to have solved the display problem in IE.  Thanks.  There are still some errors displayed in the developer tools, but I will post those in a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to GSerg's comment above and the links he referenced, I added as the first meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`.  Solved the IE display problem.