# JavaScript or CSS not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JavaScript code that toggles between DIV's on-click, but it doesn't work on IE (v.11.4) and I can't seem to understand what part is not suitable for IE..

Below is the simplified version of my code. For some reason it didn't work on jsfiddle but if you copy it in a plain html file it works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but not IE..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<style>
.holder>div {
  display: none;
}

[dir=second]>.txt2,
[dir=first]>.txt1 {
  display: block;
}

.holder_2>div {
  display: none;
}

[dir=second_2]>.txt2_2,
[dir=first_2]>.txt1_2 {
  display: block;
}
</style>
<div class="container1">
  <button onclick="toggle('first')" class="clickme">Some text</button>
  <button onclick="toggle('second')" class="clickme">Some other text</button>

    <div class="holder">
      <div class="txt1">
        <h1>Some content here</h1>
      </div>    
      <div class="txt2">
        <h1>Some different content here</h1>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <button onclick="toggle_2('first_2')" class="clickme">Some text</button>
  <button onclick="toggle_2('second_2')" class="clickme">Some other text</button>

    <div class="holder_2">
      <div class="txt1_2">
        <h1>Some content here</h1>
      </div>    
      <div class="txt2_2">
        <h1>Some different content here</h1>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var holder = document.querySelector(".holder");

function toggle(val) {
  holder.setAttribute('dir', val);
}

var holder_2 = document.querySelector(".holder_2");

function toggle_2(val) {
  holder_2.setAttribute('dir', val);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible that the problem could even be in the CSS?
All works well with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: What version of IE? And what have you done to try to narrow down the problem? You should at a minimum be able to figure out whether it's the JavaScript or CSS or a combination of them.

Comment: Try surrounding the attribute values in css with quotes i.e. `[dir="ver"]` instead of `[dir=ver]`

Comment: Not the main issue, but you have four elements with the same `id` - that is invalid.

Comment: > is the child selector. You don't have a div in .holder - that is the div. try `div.holder {display: none;}`

Comment: What does your IE console say ? Any errors ?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder It works now if you paste it to a plain html file. Not on IE ofcourse (yet..)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284083/ie10-renders-in-ie7-mode-how-to-force-standards-mode

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using `type="text/css"` instead of `type="css/stylesheet"` when importing the stylesheet. Or you can just remove the `type=...`

Also, add a DOCTYPE!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Either HTML5 or HTML4 Strict (not Transitional) are recommended for best cross-browser support. The doctype declaration should be the first thing in the html file. It goes even before the  tag.

And the end go to this website to valid your website and fix the problem
https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I already have type="text/css" in my original code, not "css/stylesheet".. Adding "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" to my doctype didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @veskimati & KC-L - Use HTML5: `<!doctype html>`. It's been many years since 4.01 was still an appropriate choice.

Comment: I am using HTML5. Ff you see my code above, I already have <!doctype html> on the first row

Comment: @veskimati - Right. Just saying, don't take the advice above to use 4.01.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tell IE that it shouldn't hobble itself and pretend that it's IE7. Add this to `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

The problem was that `document.querySelector` was failing, because it isn't a function in IE7. Yes, really, it's **that** dumb.

When I don't do that with your file, I get the error. When I add it, I don't.

If you're using IE with intranet sites, you may also want to go into Internet Options and tell it not to use "compatibility view" with them; [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557299/internet-explorer-11-disable-display-intranet-sites-in-compatibility-view-via).

For what it's worth, here's my standard boilerplate page setup, which serves me pretty well:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>...</title>
<style>
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
</style>
<!-- module scripts go here -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- content goes here -->
<!-- non-module scripts go here -->
</body>
</html>
```

That:

- Declares the HTML5 doctype to get standards mode
- Declares that the file is in UTF-8 (obviously, I then ensure that the file *is* in UTF-8)
- Sets an appropriate viewport for mobile
- Tells IE not to hobble itself
- Defaults to border-box
- Puts scripts in the right place

---

You've said that it works for you when the script is inline content in the `script` element, but not when it's in a separate file. Look in the F12 devtools for an error, probably a 404 on the file or an invalid content type, etc. Because [it definitely works](https://embed.plnkr.co/oMwkgKOqKRQBu1hcPDZp/).

Comment: I'd add to your boilerplate just `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`, so it looks good also in mobile devices. A good trick is that, if you are using [emmets](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) (default in  vs code), you can just type `! + tab` and the boilerplate will appear

Comment: @CristianTraìna - Gah! **Very** good thing to add, how was that missing?! Thank you! Added to the above and to my own copy. :-)

Comment: Thankyou for this informative answer. I actually found out that something else is causing the problem.. For some reason IE doesn't read this script from my separate JS file.. When I put an alert to my script.js file, it worked, but when I added the script shown above (to toggle DIVs) it didn't work.. But again, it works if I paste it to my php file between <script> tags.. Very weird :/

Comment: @veskimati - Where was the `<script src="yourfile.js"></script>` located in the file? Did you have the ending tag on it? You can't self-close them, for instance; `<script src="yourfile.js" />` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I closed it. I have it before </body>. But as I said, if I only put an alert to script.js, it works. But for some reason the toggle script doesn't work from there.. which is really weird.

Comment: Btw, any idea why a simple script such as 
`document.querySelectorAll("[name=image").forEach(
    ele => ele.addEventListener("change",
      (e) => e.target.closest(".form").querySelector(".sub").disabled = false
    )      
);` 
wont work on IE? :l

Comment: @veskimati - Yes -- [IE doesn't support arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/arrow-function-not-working-in-ie-why). You should be seeing a syntax error in the F12 console. I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't have `closest` either, that's a relatively new addition to the DOM, and IE is really quite old at this point.

Comment: Now that's very odd. Why does IE still have to exist after creating Edge..

Comment: @veskimati - Very big IT organizations (500+ person corps, government) move very slowly. :-)

Comment: @veskimati - See the update at the end of the answer, it [definitely works](https://embed.plnkr.co/oMwkgKOqKRQBu1hcPDZp/) on IE even in a separate file.

Comment: I'm afraid something's just wrong with my javascript.. If I only use this small script in my code, it works, but if I add the other scripts aswell, it stops working. I think the other scripts are interrupting this one..  My original script.js content: https://www.codepile.net/pile/Qg3bzzr0