# React not rendering in IE compatibility view

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, react-helmet, ie-compatibility-mode, helmet.js

I am using from create-react-app and not rendering in IE11

On IE compatibility mode is checked for intranet sites. So after deployment it uses IE5 or IE7 emulator and this shows blank page with some errors in console.

I tried to different workarounds:

1. using X-UA-Compatible tag using react-helmet
2. setting response header in IIS for X-UA-Compatible
3. [setting X-UA-Compatible header in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9338959/3722260)

None of these work.

I found this meta tag needs to [be set as first child of the head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26463309/3722260). But using react-helmet it is [not possible to place a tag at very top](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/239).

Can anyone faced similar issue?

Edit: It works fine in IE11. It is just IE compatibility issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#browser-support), react doesn't support older browsers below IE 9. You say you run it in compatibility mode which is IE 5 and IE 7. React doesn't support these two IE versions.

You could add this meta tag manually `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in the `<head>` of **public/index.html** to override the compatibility view.

<del>Besides, does your app work well in IE 11 without compatibility view? You could also follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435589/starter-create-react-app-with-ie11-polyfill-import-still-aborts-in-ie11/56439822#56439822) to make it supported on IE 11.</del>

Comment: Yes, you are right in IE11 it renders perfectly. I mean from dev tool if I change the compatibility mode to IE11 then it works perfect. 
I tried with react-helmet to put the header. Then it was added end of the head tag (not top). And it does not work. 
Does not work means still choosing IE5/IE7 emulator in IE

Comment: What about putting the meta tag manually without react-helmet? If still not works, please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and can have a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: The application is created with create-react-app script. I have no idea how to add the tag manually because there is head tag available anywhere to modify

Comment: Looks like there is a public/index.html that can be modified :)
That can be a good solution!

Comment: Yes, just add the tag in the `<head>` of **public/index.html**.

Comment: Thanks Yu Zhou. Do you want to edit your asnwer so that I can mark it answer

Comment: @masum7 ok, I've updated the answer. You could check it.

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be ECMA 6 compatibility with IE 11. You can  transpile your code to ES5 (with babel) as ES5 is supported by IE.

Comment: I guess this is because from the question it is understandable it is not IE11 issue, rather IE compatibility issue